# how to create STORED PROCEDURE to insert data in two tables according to the CustomerID

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE 
TABLE Customers(CustomerID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,FirstName nvarchar(45),LastName nvarchar(45),Address nvarchar(45))

CREATE 
TABLE Orders(OrderID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,OrderDate date,CustomerID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers](CustomerID))

CREATE
TABLE CustomersOrders(OrderID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders](OrderID),ProductName nvarchar(45),Quantity nvarchar(45),Price nvarchar(45),TotalPrice int)
```

how to create STORED PROCEDURE in to insert data in Orders and CustomersOrders two tables according to the [dbo].Customers).

Customers table has entered data with 5 CustomerID

My Database is with first table parent and second is child . Third is the child of second table. I want to

insert data in last two tables according to the CustomerID. The data has to be added with that

particular customerid.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

CREATE TABLE Customers
  (
     CustomerID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     FirstName  NVARCHAR(45),
     LastName   NVARCHAR(45),
     Address    NVARCHAR(45)
  )

CREATE TABLE Orders
  (
     OrderID    INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     OrderDate  DATE,
     CustomerID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Customers](CustomerID)
  )

CREATE TABLE CustomersOrders
  (
     OrderID     INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders](OrderID),
     ProductName NVARCHAR(45),
     Quantity    NVARCHAR(45),
     Price       NVARCHAR(45),
     TotalPrice  INT
  )

DECLARE @FirstName   NVARCHAR(45)='John',
        @LastName    NVARCHAR(45)='Smiths',
        @Address     NVARCHAR(45)='46 as str',
        @OrderDate   DATE=getdate(),
        @ProductName NVARCHAR(45)='p1',
        @Quantity    NVARCHAR(45)='1',
        @Price       NVARCHAR(45)='30',
        @TotalPrice  INT=30

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Customers
                (FirstName,
                 LastName,
                 Address)
    VALUES      (@FirstName,
                 @LastName,
                 @Address);

    INSERT INTO Orders
                (OrderDate,
                 CustomerID)
    VALUES      (@orderdate,
                 @@IDENTITY)

    INSERT INTO CustomersOrders
                (OrderID,
                 ProductName,
                 Quantity,
                 Price,
                 TotalPrice)
    VALUES      (@@IDENTITY,
                 @ProductName,
                 @Quantity,
                 @Price,
                 @TotalPrice)

    SELECT *
    FROM   customers

    SELECT *
    FROM   Orders

    SELECT *
    FROM   CustomersOrders
END
```